# Regex - Summing values in a string

Tags: regex, vba, ms-access

We get data from another company in the following formats

`374-KH-ON-PEAK|807-KH-OFF-PEAK
82.5-KH-TOTAL|8-K1-CURRENT
44.5-KH-TOTAL
65-KH-ON-PEAK|2.1-K1-ON-PEAK|164-KH-OFF-PEAK|27-K1`

These values go into a SQL Server table. The numbers represent electricity usages. I'm working on finding a way to extract the numbers and sum them together.

There is only one condition: the number must be followed by "-KH". If it is followed by "-K1" we don't need to do anything with it.

Upon inputting `"65-KH-ON-PEAK|2.1-K1-ON-PEAK|164-KH-OFF-PEAK|27-K1"`, I need to output `229` which stands for `65` + `164`

I'd prefer to find a solution using VBA for Access(For reasons related to the business's current software solutions), but I'm open to other solutions as well.

Comment: Create a function using `split()`: regex isn't necessary. First split on "|" then split each individual substring on "-". If the second value there is "KH" (and I think you can assume the first value is a number) then just add the first value to your sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using [Excel] can be done like this:**

*code:*

```
Sub test()
    Dim cl As Range, z!, x As Variant, x2 As Variant
    For Each cl In [A1:A4]
    z = 0
        For Each x In Split(cl.Value2, "|")
            If x Like "*-KH-*" Then
                For Each x2 In Split(x, "-")
                    If IsNumeric(x2) Then z = z + x2
                Next x2
            End If
        Next x
    cl.Offset(, 1).Value = z
    Next cl
End Sub
```

*another variant, without second loop (using `@shawnt00` comment below OP)*

```
Sub test()
    Dim cl As Range, z!, x As Variant
    For Each cl In [A1:A4]
    z = 0
        For Each x In Split(cl.Value2, "|")
            If x Like "*-KH-*" Then z = z + Left(x, InStr(1, x, "-") - 1)
        Next x
    cl.Offset(, 1).Value = z
    Next cl
End Sub
```

*output:*
[image]

---

**Using [Access] can be something like this:**

```
Sub test2()
    Dim z!, x As Variant
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Table1")
    Do Until rs.EOF = True
        z = 0
        For Each x In Split(rs!Field1, "|")
                If x Like "*-KH-*" Then z = z + Left(x, InStr(1, x, "-") - 1)
        Next x
        Debug.Print rs!Field1, z
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub
```

*test:*
[image]

Comment: Considering the possibility that a numeric value appears between two of the hyphens do you think it's worth eliminating the inner loop?

Comment: @shawnt00 yes, the inner loop can be eliminated, I will post additional variant which you've commented below OP, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

You would do a single bulk insert into an SQL Server table using | as the field terminator, so you would have fields like f1,f2,f3,f4. Then you can use an expression like:

```
WITH numerics
     AS ( SELECT CASE
                     WHEN PATINDEX('%-KH-%', f1) > 0
                     THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(f1, 1, PATINDEX('%-KH-%', f1) - 1) AS INT)
                     ELSE 0
                 END AS f1,
                CASE
                    WHEN PATINDEX('%-KH-%', f2) > 0
                    THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(f2, 1, PATINDEX('%-KH-%', f2) - 1) AS INT)
                    ELSE 0
                END AS f2,
                CASE
                    WHEN PATINDEX('%-KH-%', f3) > 0
                    THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(f3, 1, PATINDEX('%-KH-%', f3) - 1) AS INT)
                    ELSE 0
                END AS f3,
                CASE
                    WHEN PATINDEX('%-KH-%', f4) > 0
                    THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(f4, 1, PATINDEX('%-KH-%', f4) - 1) AS INT)
                    ELSE 0
                END AS f4
          FROM myTable )
     SELECT f1 + f2 + f3 + f4 AS rowTotal;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a Powershell script, that would give the power of regex to extract and sum the numbers. Something like the example below (I have tested the extracting from the file part but not the Access parts so they may need some tweaking):

```
$conn = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Connection 
$recordset = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Recordset
$conn.Open()
$cmd = $conn.CreateCommand()

$ado.open("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\path_to\database.accdb")
# Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 for older versions of Access

(Select-String file.txt -Pattern '[\d.]+(?=-KH)' -AllMatches) | % {
    ($_.Matches | % {
        [double]$_.Value
    } | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
} | % {
    $cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES($($_))"
    Write-Output $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
}
$conn.Close()
```

Comment: Seems pretty cool. I'm a little new to Powershell so this will take me a bit to understand but I like the idea.